# setRGB() Sets pixel to White

Tags: java, set, rgb

I'm trying to set all black pixels in a `BufferedImage` to a certain colour, but it always just sets it to white, no matter what colour I put in. However, if the `color` variable is black, then it will set it to black.

```
BufferedImage spritesheet =
     ImageIO.read(Text.class.getResourceAsStream("/HUD/font.gif"));
for(int xx = 0; xx < spritesheet.getWidth(); xx++) {
     color = new Color(200, 180, 110);
     for(int yy = 0; yy < spritesheet.getHeight(); yy++) {
        if(spritesheet.getRGB(xx, yy) == new Color(0, 0, 0).getRGB()) 
          spritesheet.setRGB(xx, yy, color.getRGB());
     }
  }
```

What have I done wrong?

[image: font]

Comment: You question is confusing.  You say the black pixels are always set to white, then you say if color is black they are set to black.  Are they always set to white or sometimes set to black?  Please clarify.

Comment: @lreeder I mean that if the `color` variable is black, then the pixels are set to that. I'll edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: Please attach "/HUD/font.gif" if you can.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe the image is 1 bit-per-pixel (i.e. black/white) and cannot store colors.  What do you get for `spritesheet.getColorModel().getPixelSize()`?

Comment: @JimGarrison I got 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jim Garrison is right.  When you loaded the GIF, it has a limited set of colors in its pallet, black and white.  When you set a pixel with a non-black color, it uses the closest color in the pallet and sets it to white.   One way to avoid this is stop reusing the same BufferedImage to write as you did to read, and create a brand new BufferedImage to save, like this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      BufferedImage spritesheet =
            ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("/tmp/GYBOD.gif"));
      BufferedImage copy = new BufferedImage(spritesheet.getWidth(), spritesheet.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
      for(int xx = 0; xx < spritesheet.getWidth(); xx++) {
         Color color = new Color(200, 180, 110);
         for(int yy = 0; yy < spritesheet.getHeight(); yy++) {
            if(spritesheet.getRGB(xx, yy) == new Color(0, 0, 0).getRGB()) {
               //spritesheet.setRGB(xx, yy, color.getRGB());
               copy.setRGB(xx, yy, color.getRGB());
            }
            else {
               copy.setRGB(xx, yy, spritesheet.getRGB(xx,yy));
            }
         }
      }

      ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("gif").next();
      writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test.gif")));
      writer.write(copy);

   }
}
```

Then when you save the GIF, Java ImageIO framework will look at the BufferedImage and create a more extensive pallet with your new colors.